# combine two arrays of arrays by key

Tags: php, arrays

How would I combine two arrays of arrays by a key?

For example:-

Array 1:

```
array (
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'A' => 'ABC'
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'A' => 'DEF'
  )
)
```

Array 2:

```
array (
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'B' => '456'
  )
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'B' => '123'
  ),
)
```

Combined array:

```
array (
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'A' => 'ABC',
    'B' => '123'

  ),
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'A' => 'DEF',
    'B' => '456'
  )
)
```

The combined array order isn't important, but it should match based on a provided field instead of natural order.

what I tried. doesn't look efficient though.

```
public function combineArraysByKey($array_1, $array_2, $key = 'id')
{
    $combined_array = array();

    foreach($array_1 as $sub_array_1) {
        foreach($array_2 as $sub_array_2) {
            if ($sub_array_1[$key] == $sub_array_2[$key]) {
                $merged_sub_array = array_merge($sub_array_1, $sub_array_2);
                array_push($combined_array, $merged_sub_array);
            }
        }
    }
    return $combined_array;
}
```

Comment: How? Probably by writing a function that combines the arrays. So I'm gonna ask: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: How important is performance here?  It would be a lot easier and faster if the key you were joining on was the key to the inner arrays.  Then `array_merge` might be able to handle most of what you need.

Comment: @kingkero, see edit. I'm interested in a proper solution though.

Comment: So your question is whether you can merge two subarrays, by a specific one of each of those subarray's keys, without using loops or restructuring the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [My code] doesn't look efficient though.

You only really need to loop once over each of the two arrays.

In your example function, the code inside the nested loops will be ran `count($array_1) * count($array_2)` times.  Whereas looping one time over each array would only be `count($array_1) + count($array_2)` times.

<sup>(Obviously, the number is the same when there are only 2 items in each array but the savings soon add up.)</sup>

So, in code, the alternative could be like:

```
$combined_array = array();
foreach(array($array_1, $array_2) as $rows) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $current_key = $row[$key];
        if (array_key_exists($current_key, $combined_array)) {
            $combined_array[$current_key] += $row;
        } else {
            $combined_array[$current_key] = $row;
        }
    }
}
return $combined_array;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:-

```
<?php

$array1 = array (
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'A' => 'ABC'
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'A' => 'DEF'
  )
);

$array2 = array (
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'B' => '456'
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'B' => '123'
  ),
);



function combineArraysByKey($array1, $array2)
{
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
        foreach($array2 as $key1 => $value2){
            if($value['id'] === $value2['id']){
                unset($value2['id']);
                $remaining_key = array_keys($value2);
                $array1[$key][$remaining_key[0]] =   $value2[$remaining_key[0]];
            }               
        }
    }
    return $array1;
}
$new_array = combineArraysByKey($array1, $array2);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/374523

Comment: thanks. I'm not sure if this is better than my function though. I don't want to do for loops if possible.